# mendelson as2 - how to copy the file to other location

Tags: b2b

We are using mendelson as2 for B2B. It copies the sent file, by sender, to inbox folder of receiver. Can we instruct it to copy the same file to another location that we required?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define events per partner that are executed after receipt. Setup a script or command there that moves your file to the new location.

Comment: Would be happy if you can share a sample script.

Comment: Depends on your OS. Unter Windows just enter "move ${filename} newlocation/${filename}".